# Pyglet: Sprite.draw() and Batch.draw() don't work, but Image.blit does

Tags: python, sprite, draw, pyglet

In pyglet, which I'm learning, Image.blit() works, but Sprite.draw() doesn't, nor Batch.draw(), even in this simple code:

```
import pyglet

win = pyglet.window.Window()

img = pyglet.resource.image('test.png')
spr = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(img)

@win.event
def on_draw():
    win.clear()
    spr.draw()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pyglet.app.run()
```

The window remains black. However, I can draw labels, for example.
THe only explaination I found was about graphic cards and "v2i" bugs with some of them, but I'm afraid to touch at pyglet's code without really knowing what I'm doing.

Comment: I don't know much about your issue, but there's another simple Python graphics framework you could use called [Pygrafix](https://github.com/nightcracker/Pygrafix) which might work for you

Comment: Thank you for the link. The API reminds pyglet, even though it's not as "Pythonic". If I really don't get any solutions, I'll consider using it, but I would like to avoid compiling Cython and Pygrafix from source since I'm on Ubuntu.

Comment: It's developed on Linux, I believe it's much easier to compile on Ubuntu than on Mac OS X.

Comment: I agree. I'll do it if there is no other solution. However, since Pygrafix is not really known, the doc' and the tutorials are very limited.

Comment: Yeah, I'll admit it has that problem. The docs are [here](http://readthedocs.org/docs/pygrafix/en/latest/), although they are lacking a bit in detail.

Comment: Until I fix the pyglet issue I'll go with Pygame. About Pygrafix, I wonder if there only purpose was to write a game lib in Cython since I find its and pyglet's API very, very similar.

Comment: Well... I know the guy who made it (I work on the project it was basically made for), it was designed to be hardware-accelerated and for high performance. He didn't like pyglet because you need to use ctypes for it, I think.

Comment: Then, it's just a different implementation of the Pyglet API? In this case, there is indeed no need for extra tutorials other than those for Pyglet.

Comment: I'm not sure. It does look quite similar although I believe there are some differences. It's not a difficult API to use though, doubt you'd really need tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third answer of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9693934/cant-draw-sprites-in-pyglet) worked for me, even though I'm using Ubuntu and not Windows. It's actually a hardware problem. I replaced the "i" with the "f" at lines 368 and 372 in "v2i" in a file I found at /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pyglet/sprite.py. Then I saved, ran my code, and everything was working.

Comment: It was actually a driver problem which seems to be fixed in Catalyst 12.4. So no more need to patch sprite.py!